# How to make Toolbar and StatusBar Translucent?

Tags: android

I need help in making them translucent. My home page is pink, then my second page is green. When I swipe to the next page I want the status bar and toolbar to change from pink to green. How will I be able to achieve this?

Comment: You want to change there color from pink to green right ? Then why do you want them to be translucent ?

Comment: Because if they are translucent then the status bar will just change color depending on the background color

Comment: You actually don't need to make them translucent. Simply Changing color on new activity would do the thing. Use something like toolbar.setBackgroundResouceDrawable(..);